# PAUSE in Batch File not working when running iMacros in Firefox for first time

Tags: batch-file, firefox, imacros, pause

Okay, so I am so confused as to how I should have properly titled my question, so I'll try my best explaining it here.

I am trying to run iMacros and some python scripts by stitching them together in a batch file. Here's a dummy code of what I wanted to to:

```
    "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m="#Current.iim"
    PAUSE
    @py %~dp0\SomePythonProgram.py %*
    PAUSE
```

The reason for adding the PAUSE is that the iMacro automation takes a while (about 8 minutes) and that it takes screenshots of certain tabs. The succeeding python program will resize those images, so once iMacros has stopped running, the user has to go back to cmd (if they've gone elsewhere) and press any key before the python program is executed.

The above code ACTUALLY WORKS when Firefox is either already open or RUNNING IN THE BACKGROUND as seen in task manager. Now, when i kill it in task manager prior to running the batch file, instead of the usual "Press any key..." cmd is stuck in this part:
[image: CMD]

Is there a way to proceed with the rest of the code (perhaps via keypresses /hotkeys)? Or do I need to replace PAUSE with something else? I've tried TRYOUT and it seemed to suffer the same issue. I'm using Windows 10 so SLEEP is not builtin,. would that help me achieve what i want?

Comment: `timeout /t 600` will wait for 600 seconds (10 minutes) and continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `timeout` and split your commands on a single line using `&&` after first command.

The reason for `&&` is for the script to only continue to the next item, if the previous command completed successfully. Where `timeout /t 600` will wait for 10 minutes before continuing to the next command.

```
start "" /w /b "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m="#Test_Macro.iim" && timeout /t 600 & @py %~dp0\SomePythonProgram.py %* & timeout /t 600
```

If you want to continue to the script, regardless if firefox started successfully, you can just use a single `&`.

To learn more on the switches available in cmd commands, you can simply open a `cmd.exe` window and type `help`

This will bring you a long list of commands available, to learn more about each, simply type the command name followed by the switch `/?` Here we can use `start` and `timeout` as an example of help switches :

```
start /?
timeout /?
```

Comment: Just tested it, no success :( Just like with my original code, it only works perfectly when Firefox is already running. Nice info about the single and double ampersands, though! Much appreciated :)

Comment: Quick info: I'm using Firefox 55.0.3 coz I see it works compatibly with the iMacro add-on version 9.0.3  :)

Comment: Woooah! That did it! What exactly did the added codes do, sir?

Comment: Great!. We need to start firefox from cmd by calling it with `start "" /w /b` where  `/w` is the wait option and `/b` to start application without creating a new window

Comment: Thanks for the solution and taking the time to educate :D This has been bugging me all day. Kudos!

Comment: My pleasure. glad I could help. As a sidenote, by using the `/w` option, it should wait for the application to terminate, so you might get away with not using the `timeout` after the imacro, else it will finish in +- 8 minutes, then only start the timeout ad wait another 10 minutes.

Comment: Damn, this just supercharged my codes to a whole new level. Noted!

Comment: @JohnnyDerpp let me add some more info in the answer, you can then follow instructions when you have some time.